# How to pass an int slice to "$in" using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, slice, mgo

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a query using the bson functionality of `mgo`. I'm simply trying to do `{'search_id': {'$in': [1,2,4,7,9]}}`, but I can't work out how to do it in `mgo`.

I have a slice of `int`s, and tried passing that directly:

```
toRemove := []int{1,2,4,7,9}
err = coll.Remove(bson.M{"search_id": bson.M{"$in": toRemove}})
```

I saw another post which suggested I needed to use `[]interface{}`, but that doesn't work either:

```
toRemoveI := make([]interface{}, len(toRemove))
for idx, val := range toRemove {
    toRemoveI[idx] = val
}
err = coll.Remove(bson.M{"search_id": bson.M{"$in": toRemoveI}})
```

I've looked through he docs and other questions here and on gh, but most questions involving slices seem to be about getting data into a slice as opposed to what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original proposal (passing an `[]int` value) has no flaws, it's valid to do that.

What the problem is is that you use [`Collection.Remove()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Remove) which finds and removes a **single** document matching the provided selector document. So your proposed solution will remove **exactly 1 document**, one whose `search_id` is contained in the slice you passed. If no such document is found (and the session is in safe mode, see [`Session.SetSafe()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.SetSafe)), [`mgo.ErrNotFound`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#ErrNotFound) is returned.

Instead use [`Collection.RemoveAll()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.RemoveAll) which finds and removes **all** documents matching the selector:

```
toRemove := []int{1,2,4,7,9}
info, err := c.RemoveAll(bson.M{"search_id": bson.M{"$in": toRemove}})

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to remove: %v", err)
} else {
    log.Printf("Removed %d documents.", info.Removed)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I did spot it was removing just one, but thought it was dodgy data being passed to the bson functions.